# Problems with producing a specific readout while writing java to file

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, jinternalframe

I am trying to save a specific `jInternalFrame` to a file as a picture. The internalframe is located in a `jFrame` in a `jTabbedPane` in a `jTabbedPane`. The readout is fine except its 50% of the internal frame. It does not want to show the rest of the readout so there is no error. I want to expand the view of the image... Can anyone help me?

Here is the method which is activated via an on-click listener:

```
private void tallennus() {
  setContentPane(jInternalFrame1); 
  this.pack();

  Dimension size = jInternalFrame1.getSize();
  BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, (int)PageSize.A4.getHeight()+(int)PageSize.A4.getHeight(),
  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
  g2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  g2.clearRect(jInternalFrame1.getX(),jInternalFrame1.getY(),size.width,(int)PageSize.A4.getHeight() + (int)PageSize.A4.getHeight());
  g2.fillRect(jInternalFrame1.getX(),jInternalFrame1.getY(),size.width,(int)PageSize.A4.getHeight() + (int)PageSize.A4.getHeight());
  g2.scale(1, 0.75);

  super.setPreferredSize(size);
  super.paintComponents(g2);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

- don't paint by using `paintComponents(`) use `paintComponent()`
- don't paint backgroud to the [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) by using [paintComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) directly
- put there [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) or `JComponent`
- if you want to only to display image, load image as [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) the the [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)
- use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead of `JInternalFrames`
- for real anser sooner edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: thank you for being willing to help... I am currently attempting to apply this answer into practise... it gave me some good ideas.. SSCCE will be difficult to pull of becuase the code page is over 10,000 lines long so parsing to include the neccecary becomes and issue.

Comment: I applied these notes but the issue seems to be that since the Jinternalframe is not entirely visible but exsists in a JScrollPane it gets partially cut off... so i should be looking into presenting non-visible components i assume

Comment: you have to call `pack() to the container or container must be once time visible on the screen if you want to get some usefull information

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the thoughts... gave me all the help i needed on approaching the problem.. I realize some of this code is redundant but i will still post it.

```
  private void tallennus(){

  JPanel drawingPanel = new JPanel();
  drawingPanel.setSize(new Dimension((int)PageSize.A4.getWidth(),(int)PageSize.A4.getHeight()));

 jPanel11.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
 jScrollPane27.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
 jPanel11.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
 jTabbedPane1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
 jPanel10.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  drawingPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  drawingPanel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
  add(drawingPanel);

 Container cont = jInternalFrame1;
jInternalFrame1.pack();
String Ifra = jInternalFrame1.getComponents().toString();

 BufferedImage sama = (BufferedImage) cont.createImage((int)PageSize.A4.getWidth(),(int)PageSize.A4.getHeight()+(int)PageSize.A4.getHeight());
 drawingPanel.add(cont);
  setContentPane(drawingPanel);

 this.pack();

Dimension size = drawingPanel.getSize();
  BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, (int)PageSize.A4.getHeight()+400,
  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
   g2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  g2.clearRect(0,0,size.width,(int)PageSize.A4.getHeight() + 400);
 g2.clipRect(40, 90, 1200, 1450);

  g2.drawString(Ifra, TOP_ALIGNMENT, TOP_ALIGNMENT);
  g2.drawImage(sama, null, cont);
  g2.clipRect(40, 90, 1200, 1450);

  this.pack();

  paint(g2);

  try{
  ImageIO.write(image,"jpeg",new File("snap.jpg"));
  }
  catch(Exception e){}
    }
```